# AngularJS - Persist value across opened tabs/windows using ngStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

We ran into an issue when language is changed from one tab, it is not being reflected in another already opened tab. We are using below code to set language in cookie.

```
if (angular.equals(addcookie, "Yes")) {
$cookieStore.put('lang', langKey);
}
```

We tried below code to set language in localstorage

```
$localStorage.language = langKey; //EN/FR
$translate.use(langKey); //translate language
```

The language is set, but if user changes language from one tab, it is not reflecting it already opened tab.

Further we tried like below, though not recommended

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
           language : langKey
       });

$scope.$watch(function() {
     return angular.toJson($scope.$storage);
       }, function() {
          console.log('The language is *** '+$scope.$storage.language);
   });
```

But the above also does not seem to be working.

How do we use ngStorage extension in order to reflect the language change across all the opened tabs/windows ? Also does it work with open windows too apart from open tabs ?

We want a user to have multiple browser tabs/windows open of the same website and dynamically change the content on both tabs (Which are the same view) based on the localstorage.

Source - https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Having multiple windows/tabs open seems counter-intuitive if you're building a SPA. Anyway, I think the best achievable way to do this is with web sockets.

Comment: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Using ngStorage, it'll get new value as soon as when changed but to change the language of page, you've to at least reload the route/state. (Here I'm considering you're using https://angular-translate.github.io/ module)

Comment: The page from where the language is changed does not reload but managed using cookies and translate. But the same is not reflecting in other open tab/window until reloaded. As soon as user click on Apply button, languageCtrl is called and uses `$translate.use(langKey);` for translation and effect is seen on page without reload.

Comment: Can use storage events or postMessage api. to listen to other windows